# How to make villager babies stay babies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map and I need some of the villager's children to stay children! I tried age/forced age of -1000000, but when I summoned it, it was an adult! I don't do mods, and I'm not very good at McEdit. Can someone help?

The command I am currently using:

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,CareerLevel:1,Age:-1000000000,ForcedAge:-10000‌​00000}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what command you tried? What did you read about /summon command syntax?

Comment: ok, I used this command:  `/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,CareerLevel:1,Age:-1000000000,ForcedAge:-1000000000}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Give yourself a repeating command block: `/give @s repeating_command_block`
- Place it down near spawn (in the spawn chunks to be exact).
- Click on <kbd>Needs redstone</kbd> to set it to <kbd>Always active</kbd> and write into the text box: `execute as @e[type=villager,tag=baby,nbt={Age:-1}] run data merge entity @s {Age:-1000000}` (remember to finish with <kbd>Done</kbd>)
- Go close to the villager you want to stay a baby and enter into chat: `/tag @e[type=villager,sort=nearest,limit=1] add baby`
- Repeat the last step for every villager that should stay a baby.

Setting the age to a very low negative number is only a temporary solution, for example your `Age:-1000000` would expire after about two weeks. My solution keeps working forever.

Comment: But, when I entered the /summon command, it came out an adult _immediately_. And the repeating command block would make a LOT of lag. I have a very weak laptop, and it doesn't handle lag very well...

Comment: The command block just changes something back that the game already changes for hundreds of entities per tick, so it shouldn't be too bad. In 1.13 you'll be able to slightly improve the performance by replacing the selector with `@e[type=villager,tag=baby,nbt={Age:-1}`. For now you could limit the radius (like `,r=30`) if you know where the baby villager will definitely be. That the summoned villager is an adult first is no problem, it will turn into a baby when you run the command.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: Of course you also need a closing square bracket at the end of the selector.

Comment: It's a very good solution to the problem. I will try it! Thanks!

Comment: The latest upvote on this ancient answer just gave me the role "trusted user" on gamingSE. :D

Answer (score 0):

This baby villager will stay a baby for over 3 years of being loaded:

```
/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Age:-2000000000}
```

Here is one of those guys I summoned a long time ago.  He is in my command block graveyard.
[image: Villager]

Comment: That still doesn't work for me. When I summoned the villager, even though it had an age of -1000000000, it came out an adult! I don't know why, but no matter what I do, it comes out an adult!

Comment: I just used your exact command from the comments.  It produced a baby villager.  I am not sure why it isn't working for you.  What version do you play?

Comment: In that particular world, 1.12.2. But that's the most recent version other than snapshots of 1.13, but I don't like snapshots...